# how to achieve “for(int i,i<=3,i++){}” of C++ in Mathematica

Tags: scoping

when i use Mathematica to do some small programmings, i always need to pay attention to variables-namings, i just wonder is there a way to achieve “for(int i,i<=3,i++){}” of C++ in Mathematica.

After some answers:

i'm sorry i have not state the question clearly, before your answers, i knew the For[] function, what i want emphasis is variable-localization. and after my test, variables in For[] will exist after For[], but Do[] does have a good variables-localizations, thanks Nasser.
In a word, let's use Do[] function!

Comment: The For command was designed just for this purpose.

Comment: You can use 'Do' loop. Mathematica automatically localizes the loop variable. Do loop is better than using For loop.

Comment: It is recommend to ignore `For` in Mathematica.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How is "i always need to pay attention to variables-namings" related to for loop?

Comment: If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from. For now: `For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
 Echo[i];
 ]`

Comment: i'm sorry i have not  state the question clearly, before your answers, i knew the For[] function, what i want emphasis is variable-localization.   and after my test, variables in For[] will exist after  For[], but Do[] does have a good variables-localizations,  thanks Nasser

Answer (score 6):

When we write `for(int i=0,i<=3,i++){}` in C++, as opposed to `int i; for(i=0,i<=3,i++){}`, the variable name *`i`* is declared to be an `int` in the scope of the `{}`.

In *Mathematica*, we say that such a variable is localized. For example, in the Details section of the documentation for [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) we read that "`Table` effectively uses `Block` to localize values or variables."  This means *Mathematica* ***always*** localizes the index of the `Table` command.

Unlike `Table`, the variable name of the index of the `For` command (in *Mathematica*) is not localized.  We could localize the variable name by wrapping the `For` in a `Block`.  For example, `Block[{i},For[i=0,i<=3,++i, Echo@i]]`.  However, it would be better to use the `Do` command or `Table` or  any of some other [`Looping Constructs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LoopingConstructs.html)

The Details section of the documentation for [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Do.html) also says "`Do` effectively uses `Block` to localize values or variables."  This would be the preferred way to localize the index.

Comment: thanks, your answer clearly explained the principle and mechanism of localization of Table[] Do[].